# How to add the Guardian API to dependencies

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app, which gets news from The Guardian newspaper. The documentation isn't clear about dependencies. And there is no info about that anywhere.
Thank you in advance

https://github.com/matarrese/content-api-the-guardian

Dunno if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to install dependency to use the api check this api documentation
https://open-platform.theguardian.com/documentation/search